# javascript renaming "sub-local" variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

> Variables declared within a JavaScript function, become LOCAL to the
>   function.
>
> "Local variables have local scope: They can only be accessed within
>   the function."

i'm not sure if i understand this

```
cls = function(){
    var abel = '';
    $.each([ ('1','null') ,('2','two')],function(n,val){
        if ( val[0] == 1 ) {
            abel = val[1];
            return false;
        };
    });
}
console.log( abel )
```

will variable 'abel' become global variable?  will it be accessible outside cls function? if yes, how to handle such situation?

Comment: "*will variable 'abel' become global variable?"* No. "*will it be accessible outside cls function?"* No. You could just run the code and verify that yourself. Btw, `('1','null')` probably doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Have you tried running the function and looking at the output?

Comment: i'ts a lot more complex than this. cls is nested in a couple of other functions. so i'm not sure how to test it. contents of array are just for example

Comment: Simplify and extract: https://jsfiddle.net/LbLyqq6p/ .

Comment: lol stupid me. sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “The two most common elements in the universe are Hydrogen and
>   stupidity.”